# Unknown 'achievement'

Tags: support, notifications, reputation-history

Recently, on Stack Overflow, I received a notification stating +8 points on a question that I answered. But when I checked that question there was no activity on my answer - no upvotes, no comments and it wasn't selected as the answer.

At first, I thought someone might've upvoted it then it soon after was downvoted but, I guess, that would create two notifications, one for each event.

Then why was there an increase in my rep when there was no change in the state of the answer that I submitted?

Comment: Some questions and answers are such that ignoring them is worthy of votes in itself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Reputation notifications are grouped together in the top bar. You can see them separately in [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343488/zhirzh?tab=reputation).

Play around with the 'post' and 'time' view to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Jeroen's answer covered everything you need to know. But just as an added note, once you reach 1000 reputation, it'll make more sense to you. At 1000 reputation, you get the ability to view vote counts, so when I click on your vote total of "0", I see this:

[image: vote count view]

+10 for the upvote, -2 for the downvote, you get a net +8 reputation, even though the upvote and downvote cancel each other out and show up as 0 votes on your post. It all works out :)